# Combining two SOQL but getting error

Tags: apex, soql

I have many column on my object. I was getting error

> Query is either selecting too many fields or the filter conditions are too complicated.

so trying to split in two query the combining result. I am receiving error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(SObject) from the type SObject

from last statement while trying to add, can anyone please help

```
sObject sobj;
sObject sobj1;
sObject sobj2;
String objName = objId.getSObjectType().getdescribe().getName();
//getting the describe of the object passed to get the fields
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[] r = Schema.describeSObjects(new String[] {objName});
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fields = r[0].fields.getMap() ;
Id referenceId;  
List<String> lstrequiredfields=new List<String>();    
List<Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMapValues = fields.values();
String theQuery =  'SELECT ';
String theQuery1 = 'SELECT ';
integer colCount1 = 0;
for(Schema.SObjectField s : fldObjMapValues)
{

    if (colCount1 < 400){
        String theName = s.getDescribe().getName();
        theQuery += theName + ',';
        colCount1 = colCount1 +1;
    }else {
        String theName = s.getDescribe().getName();
        theQuery1 += theName + ',';
        colCount1 = colCount1 +1;
    }
}
system.debug('Total Coulum Count >> '+colCount1);
// Trim last comma
theQuery = theQuery.subString(0, theQuery.length() - 1);
theQuery = theQuery + ' FROM ' + objName + ' where id =' + '\'' + objId + '\'';
theQuery1 = theQuery1.subString(0, theQuery1.length() - 1);
theQuery1 = theQuery1 + ' FROM ' + objName + ' where id =' + '\'' + objId + '\'';
    sobj  = Database.query(theQuery);
    sobj1 = Database.query(theQuery1); 
    Map<Id, SObject> historyMap = new Map<Id, SObject>(sobj);

    for(Sobject record: sobj1) {
        Map<String, Object> values = record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
        SObject temp = historyMap.get(record.Id);
        for(String field: values.keySet()) {
            temp.put(field, values.get(field));
        }
    }
    sobj.clear();
    sobj.addAll(historyMap.values());
```

Update : Above code is fixed and working fine.

Comment: You cannot get more than 50000 rows in 1 transaction

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving verbatim in the body of your question.

Comment: It is good that you added the error you were getting before trying to solve for it. But what is your new error?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal : I am not getting error for many row. It is for many column. Object has many column so limit got exceeded for query which i am building. I am trying to split and add result into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current error has nothing to do with SOQL *per se*; it's really a type error.

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(SObject) from the type SObject

You seem to be trying to combine your query results by doing

```
sobj.add(sObj1);
sobj.add(sObj2);
```

but `sobj` is not a `List<sObject>`; it's just

```
sObject sobj;
```

Further, `add()` adds *one record* to a `List`, not the contents of another `List`.

To fix this, you can do

```
sObj1.addAll(sObj2);
```

and get rid of `sobj` entirely.

There isn't a built-in way to merge the fields populated in two different copies of the same sObject. You'd need to write your own logic using the methods available on the [`sObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) class, such as `get()` and `put()`. You could iterate over [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) on the one object and add its values to the other.

The operation you're trying to do seems likely to push one or more platform limits. You'll need to keep an eye on the performance of your code and test thoroughly against volume.

Comment: Thanks David, I can see that error not coming after your suggestion. But is there way i can combine the result in one column sObject sobj( Single Record). Both query has half field and finally want to merge them into single record. My program down the line refer only sObject sobj not List.

Comment: I've added some suggestions, @ArvindSingh, but this will be a bit complex.

Comment: Many Thanks david, I was able to solve this using getPopulatedFeildsAsmap(). It took some time to build this logic. I will add code if someone facing similar issue.